# Is there a concept for a cross platform GUI?

Tags: opengl, webgl, opengl-es, three.js

I have developed a C++ core application, which needs a relatively simple GUI, like a mind map. Now I wish to find a multipurpose solution for the visualization. So far my effort:

- three.js (webgl) in browser
- QT (qml) rendering three.js in a container , also win/lin/osx solution

Everything works and I am enthusiastic to see the same code run on so many platforms. But the problem is, that I'm using some newly released features of three.js and qt uses an older version. More specific: there is no way to render a css3drenderer object.

Now I almost gave up and tried to find an OpenGL solution (imgui?) or some funky solution like electron (node.js).

But it seems to be, that there is no way and I have to develop native apps, may be based on OpenGL ES.

I will appreciate any concept for my GUI solution

Comment: OpenGL ES is for [embedded platforms](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) like cell phones. macOS definitely doesn't support it, and I'm pretty sure neither Linux nor Windows do either. They all support straight OpenGL, though.

Comment: Do you mean, there is no backdoor to display OpenGL ES content in a native app?

Comment: No there's no such backdoor. OpenGL and OpenGL ES are fairly similar, and portions of your code may work on both, but usually there are some parts that will not. For example on macOS you have a `CGLContextObject` that represents the context, whereas on iOS you use an [`EAGLContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html).